# Fetch MQTT Sensor Value using Node-Red transfer to MySQL

Tags: esp32, node-red, arduino-ide

I use ESP32 and HC-SR04 Sensor to measure level of Garbage bin for my IOT Project.
In Arduino script, I use this script for publish sensor value to MQTT Broker

```
 char distanceString [8];
 dtostrf(distanceCm, 1, 2, distanceString);
 // Prints the distance in the Serial Monitor
 Serial.print("Distance (cm): ");
 Serial.println(distanceString);
 client.publish("distance", distanceString);
```

When debugging, the feed show data like this:

```
5/18/2023, 2:11:49 PM node: msg.payload
distance : msg.payload : number
19.18
```

and using this flow to configure and transfer data to MySQL [image]

I use default configuration for MQTT in and JSON, in Function I use script like below:

```
var src = payload;
msg.topic = 'INSERT INTO transaction_log (distance,Timestamp) VALUES ('src',CURTIME());'
return msg;
```

But the simple step still make me confuse, there are error and debug show:

```
5/18/2023, 2:25:03 PM node: Send data to DB
function : (error)
"SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'src' (body:line 2)"
5/18/2023, 2:25:03 PM node: a2c6593749f38d03
msg : string[28]
"Unexpected end of JSON input"
```

Where's my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First line of function node should be `var src = msg.payload`

Second line should be

```
 msg.topic = 'INSERT INTO transaction_log (distance,Timestamp) VALUES (' + src + ',CURTIME());'
```

String concatenation needs to use `+`